# ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'demo.mp4') error. Check if the path exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ffmpeg, recordrtc

I'm trying to convert recordRTC webm file to mp4 using ffmpeg.js library in nextjs project, during conversion showing this issue

```
ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'demo.mp4') error. Check if the path exists
```

```js
const stopRecording = async () => {
    if (recordRef.current) {
        let blob = {}
        recordRef.current.stopRecording(function(url) {
            blob = recordRef.current.getBlob()
        });
        const webmFile = new File([blob], 'video.webm', {
            type: 'video/webm'
        })
        convertBobToMpeg(webmFile)
    }
}


const convertBobToMpeg = async (webmFile) => {
    await ffmpeg.load();
    await ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', 'video.webm', await fetchFile(webmFile))
    ffmpeg.run('-i', 'video.webm', 'demo.mp4');


    const data = await ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'demo.mp4');
    setVideo_obj(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data.buffer], {
        type: 'video/mp4'
    })))
}
```

Comment: What is the specific error that you are getting? Your post does not explain the error you're encountering

Comment: hi @SheaHunterBelsky, I'm getting this error, 

ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'demo.mp4') error. Check if the path exists in the console.

Comment: Can you confirm whether or not `demo.mp4` exists at the correct location, relative to the location of this JavaScript file in your filesystem?